# Users uploaded and Search results lists suddenly stopped showing the title and playlist when embedding Youtube

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have a webpage with youtube playlists displayed in an iframe by embedding them. They have always showed the title of the video as well as an icon to open the playlist in the top left corner.

Suddenly a few days ago this stopped working and now the **title is not shown and neither is the playlist icon**. Title isnt even shown when you play the videos, very confusing as you dont know what you are watching.

I have not changed anything on my side. Have Youtube changed something? There are no parameters available that allow you to hide the title, or to force showing it either. I dont understand the logic in not displaying the title.

Here examples to show you what I mean.

This is how it should look, title and a playlist icon in upper left corner, and have looked in the past on all three below URL's:

https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLbpi6ZahtOH6Blw3RGYpWkSByi_T7Rygb

This is how it should not look and how it suddenly looks since a few days back:

https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=YouTube

No title, No option to open playlist. Still they are supposed to look the same as first one!

My reference for parameters: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Grateful for any help on this matter!

Comment: Check the console wether there are errors or not. Maybe this was a temp error by YouTube - not the first time it happens.

Comment: Yes. This was an error from YouTubes side and they have now fixed it and thanked me for calling their attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error from YouTubes side and they have now fixed it.

They even thanked me for calling their attention to it.

They also updated it to look better then before. Now the playlist menu is on the top right.

Comment: Thank you for post your own answer. Please accept your own answer and (*if might I ask*) - can you share the response from YouTube? - did you post a Issue Tracker or similar communication with them?

Comment: I posted it to multiple places and submitted feedback etc and I cant remember exactly where they replied right now Im sorry.